# what does eval on directory path do?

Tags: perl

```
$dir  =~ s/\$\&/\$src/g;
$pattern =~ s/\$\&/\$src/g;

$dir1 = eval( $dir );
$file = eval( $pattern );
```

Question about the above, $dir is a directory and $pattern is the pattern of a certain filename.  What does eval accomplish?  seems like it's replacing $& in the string with the variable &src as a string literal but how does eval on a directory path or filename work?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that these strings happen to contain path-like information is irrelevant to what it's doing.

The 1st 2 lines replace '$&' with '$src'.

The 2nd 2 lines (the evals) force a re-interpolation on the strings, replacing '$src' with the contents of $src. (plus, of course, expanding out any other variables that are named in the strings).

Unless your leaving out something important, these could both be done in a single step by removing the backslash from the substitutions' replacement string, like `($dir1 = $dir) =~ s/\$\&/$src/g`